# How to update a user after a certain time in Node.js and Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How to automatically deduct credits from a user's available credits according to his active services renewal date?

Let me describe what is the current scenario. Currently, I am working on an Express app which is basically a billing system which will automatically manage clients and charge them according to his active services. But I stuck! How to auto deduct credits from the user's account and renew the service or take the service on hold if he (the user) does not have sufficient balance.

Here is what I have.

**Services Schema:**

```
var mongoose= require('mongoose');
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true
  },
  services:{
    username: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    package:  {type: String, required: true},
    domain:   {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    status: String,
    dateAdded: {type: Date, default: Date.now },
    lastRenewed: Date,
    nextRenewal: Date,
    renewalCost: Number // Renewal Cost Of The Service.
  }
})

module.exports  = mongoose.model('Service', Schema);
```

**User Schema:**

```
var mongoose= require('mongoose');

var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name:{
    type: String,
    min: 1,
    required: true
  },
  username:{
        type: String,
        unique: true
  },
  password:{
    type: String, // Storing Hashed Password
    required: true
  },
  salt:{
    type: String
  },
  meta: {
    email: String,
    phone: Number,
    dateOfBarth: String,
    address: {
      companyName: String,
      address1: String,
      address2: String,
      city: String,
      state: String
   }
 },

 credit:{type: Number, default: 0},  // Avilable Credits
 isAdmin: {type: Boolean, default: false} // If The User Is Admin Or Not?


});

module.exports  = mongoose.model('User', Schema);
```

Now I want to run a query or a function (or something like it) on the "nextRenewal" date and deduct the renewal cost from the user's available Credits and save the user and also extend the next renewal date.

> Answer: Use  npmjs.com/package/node-schedule To schedule the job.
>
> Thanks to @Kilizo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) the Service and use Populate to populate the user object within it.

Untested code:

```
Service.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: serviceId }).populate('user').then((service) => {    
  if(service.user.credit > 10) {
   service.user.credit -= 10;
   service.services.nextRenewal = //newDate;
   service.user.save();
   service.save();
  }
})
```

Comment: Actually, it is not the issue. The main Issue is To run the update function automatically on nextRenewal Date.

Comment: You will need to schedule a script to check nextRenewal dates for each service

Comment: Yap Thank you for it. But I have some doubt of it. Suppose if I add a task to run the update function . and do a server restart the server. Will the task still run on time or not?

Comment: as long as your startup script restarts your scheduler then it will run

Comment: How to add a batch of jobs at once? Can you please provide the code?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways to do that:

- using **cron** jobs
- using **windows scheduler**

**Windows scheduler**: you can create a project with the functionality that you require and add that project as task in windows scheduler and schedule that task according to your required date.

**cron**: you can use cron jobs to schedule your task according to your required date.

I would suggest writing a **cron** for this, as this runs on web server and will work until your server stops, while windows scheduler runs on your local machine and will only work if your machine is running.

Comment: Suppose If I have More than 10,000 services active, then should I add 10,000 Chron jobs? There should another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To run the update function automatically on next Renewal Date you have to use cron job.Please find more information on cron job : [Cron Job](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)